# In Vagrant, do I get boot_timeout error because my processor doesn't support Virtualization Technology (VT-d)?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, development-environment, virtualization

I'm trying to setup a development environment with **Vagrant**, but every time I run the command `vagrant up` in my terminal I get the following error message:

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
>   the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
>   Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
>   are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
>   Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
>   as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

I've tried almost every solution I found on the internet, but the error still shows up. Some solution indicated that this may occur because my computer's processor doesn't support **Virtualization**, so I searched to find out if my processor support it or not and I found the next relevant specification (my processor's type and model is: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHZ`):

[image]

Do I get the above-mentioned error because my computer's processor doesn't support **Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d)**? And is there any solution for that?

Comment: Did you also tried enabling Virtualisation at bios level. Before doing with vagrant, try creating the virtualbox sample vm, and try install with general basic image of ubuntu. if it works, then there is no problem with your machine. `try first without vagrant` :)